concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly... from FastAPI endpoint access
I have been trying to collect youtube video related data in Processes to speed up collecting and got the following error
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending. when trying to access the functionality via FastAPI endpoint (it works ok when i try to run the script itself using  if __name__ == '__main__':
screenshot of multiprocessing execution via if _name_ == '_main_':
)
fast_api.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from load_functions import download_multiple_videos_and_subtitles
from typing import Dict, List
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


# Define the data model for the request body
class DownloadRequest(BaseModel):
    urls: List[str]  # List of URLs
    what_to_download: Dict[str, bool]  #

@app.post("/download-video-info")
def read_item(request: DownloadRequest):
    # {
    #     "urls": [
    #         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7X9w_GIm1s"
    #     ],
    #     "what_to_download": {
    #         "video": true, "audio": true, "subtitles": true
    #     }
    # }
    urls = request.urls
    what_to_download = request.what_to_download
    return download_multiple_videos_and_subtitles(urls, what_to_download)

load_functions.py
import datetime
import multiprocessing

from pytubefix import YouTube
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from pytubefix import Playlist

def download_video(url, shared_video_dict):
    yt = YouTube(url)
    video_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    sanitized_title = yt.title.replace(" ", "_")
    video_filename = f"{timestamp}_{sanitized_title}_video.mp4"

    video_stream.download(filename=video_filename)
    print(f"Downloaded: {video_filename}")
    shared_video_dict[url] = video_filename


def download_audio(url, shared_audio_dict):
    yt = YouTube(url)
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    sanitized_title = yt.title.replace(" ", "_")
    audio_filename = f"{timestamp}_{sanitized_title}_audio"
    ys = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
    ys.download(filename=audio_filename, mp3=True)
    print(f"Downloaded: {audio_filename}")
    # data[url]["audio"] = audio_filename
    shared_audio_dict[url] = audio_filename

def download_multiple_videos_and_subtitles(urls, what_to_download):
    try:
        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
            shared_video_dict = manager.dict()
            shared_audio_dict = manager.dict()
            shared_subtitles_dict = manager.dict()
            with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
                # Schedule both video and subtitle download concurrently for each URL
                futures = []
                for url in urls:
                    if what_to_download.get("video"):
                        futures.append(executor.submit(download_video, url, shared_video_dict))
                    # if what_to_download.get("subtitles"):
                    #     futures.append(executor.submit(download_and_process_subtitles, url))
                    if  what_to_download.get("audio"):
                        futures.append(executor.submit(download_audio, url, shared_audio_dict))

                # Wait for all tasks to complete
                for future in futures:
                    print(future.result())
            return dict(shared_video_dict), dict(shared_audio_dict), dict(shared_subtitles_dict)
    except Exception as exc:
        return exc


def get_channel_videos_list(url):
    pl = Playlist(url).video_urls
    what_to_download = {
        "video": True, "audio": True, "subtitles": False
    }
    return download_multiple_videos_and_subtitles(pl, what_to_download)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_channel_videos_list("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLw1mmuEtljJDcwB5lbjuse-OzPNJH26gG"))

could you please take a look at the provided (tell if something is needed to be added from my side) an give some piece of advice to resolve it, thanks in advance

I think your question is confusing.  You say that it works when you run "the script itself" with a name guard statement (if __name__ == "main").  But that's the code you have shown us.  So if this code is working, then what problem are you trying to solve?  It is quite normal (and often necessary) to run a multiprocessing script with a name guard.
